# NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR

Tags: npm, gulp, npm-install

I tried to run `npm install --save-dev gulp-iconfont` and got this message:

`gyp WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR`

How to fix this?

Comment: Have you found a solution? Thanks.

Comment: @FelixG thanks for reminding to post the solution, please refer my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have nvm setup and when my npm pointer was on older node `v4.4.0` I got the message warning ".... is deprecated, please use ....." :

```
sh$ nvm list
->  v4.4.0
    v5.8.0
```

But when I switched to new node `v5.8.0` and installed `gulp-iconfont` I did not get any warning.

```
sh$ nvm list
    v4.4.0
->  v5.8.0
```

Comment: These versions you see from nvm list are the node versions, not npm versions

Comment: Did the change as suggested by @Johan

Comment: I switched my node version to older  and it worked for me.